# DC mini pump not working when connected with IR sensor and MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, infrared

I have designed a circuit which uses an  `IRF540N`. The circuit is for switching on the pump when the IR sensor is activated.

I have checked the output with a multimeter and it's showing 4.5V. Also, I've added pulldown resistor of value `47K` along with it. Whenever I connect a LED it's working fine, but when I connect the mini pump it's not working. The pump only requires 3V.

I also tried the same with TIP31C the same result, bulb glows but motor doesn't work

**Bulb glows but motor doesn't**

[image]

Comment: We can't answer questions about schematics we can't see.

Comment: Okay I'l add it.

Comment: *I have designed a circuit* Then show it, no circuit means I'm moving on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton then how is the LED got lit

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Can you please check

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you please check

Comment: @ChrisStratton Can you please check

Comment: Your drawing is not a shematic.  It is also either irrelevant or nonsense - you've shown a PNP BJT but you claim to have an N-channel FET which requires completely different wiring and input sense.   And then you have this IR circuit board of unkown behavior.  There are many questions here showing how to properly use an FET as a low side switch to drive a motor, start by studying those.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I initially tried it using a FET now I have switched to TIP31C and still it is not working

Comment: Of course not, the TIP31 is an NPN, this picture you copied from somewhere shows a circuit for a PNP transistor such as the depicted TIP32

Comment: To other readers: The schematic seems to have come from [this Instructable page](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Automatic-Alcohol-Dispenser-No-Arduino-Needed/). @ManojPerumarath - Hi, when you are asking about someone else's design, it helps for you to give a link to the original source. In this case, that Instructable includes some important details about the types of transistor which can be used in that circuit.

Comment: You need to get straightened out PNP vs NPN vs NMOS vs PMOS. Does your IR sensor output Vcc or GND when something is detected?

Answer (score 1):

TIP32 is a bipolar transistor not a MOSFET. In a MOSFET varying gate voltage will modulate collector current, in a bipolar such modulation is done by controlling base current.

TIP32 hFE is 25, with 1k base resistor, that would be something like Ib = 5mA, Ic ~ 25*5mA = 125mA. Which seems rather low for a pump.

Check how much current your pump uses (connect in series with a ampmeter to 5v if you don't have the datasheet). And change the resistor base to allow at least that as collector current.

Or you can switch to a real MOSFET, it will be simpler to control. IRF9540 is a very common P-channel MOSFET you can use. Keep the Pulldown 47k resistor but remove the 1k one (gate-source leakage is 100nA, so won't overload your proximity sensor)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the same configuration.

Just Replace 1k resistor with 220. It will 100% work. Pump needs more current.